# Proportional linear maps - is my reasoning correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $V,W$ be $K$-linear spaces and $f,g \in \textrm{Hom}(V,W)$. Assume that $\forall v\in V~ \exists c_v\in K: g(v) = c_v f(v)$. Show that $\exists c \in K: g = cf$ 
>   $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
> \DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$

I think I solved it but could you please check whether it's correct?

> The thesis is trivial if $\rank f = 0$.
>
> Denote $c_v$ as $c(v)$. Notice that if $v \in \ker f$ then $v \in \ker g$.
>
> Let $\lbrace f(\alpha_k)\rbrace_{k \in I}$ be the base of $\im f$. Let's consider $g(\alpha_x + \alpha_y)$, with $x\neq y$. We have
>   $$g(\alpha_x + \alpha_y) = c(\alpha_x + \alpha_y) [f(\alpha_x) + f(\alpha_y)]$$
>   $$g(\alpha_x + \alpha_y) = g(\alpha_x) + g(\alpha_y) = c(\alpha_x)f(\alpha_x) + c(\alpha_y)f(\alpha_y)$$
>   Hence
>   $$f(\alpha_x)[c(\alpha_x+\alpha_y) - c(\alpha_x)] + f(\alpha_y)[c(\alpha_x+\alpha_y) - c(\alpha_y)] = 0$$
>   Since $f(\alpha_x), f(\alpha_y)$ are linearly independent, we have $c(\alpha_x+\alpha_y) = c(\alpha_y) = c(\alpha_x)$
>
> Consequently, for any $i \in I$ we have $c(\alpha_i) = c$, where $c$ is some constant. 
>   Now we can write for some $v' \in \ker f$
>   $$g(v) = g\left(\sum_{i\in I} r_i \alpha_i+ v'\right) = \sum_i r_i g(\alpha_i) = \sum_i r_i c(\alpha_i) f(\alpha_i) = \sum_i r_i c f(\alpha_i) = c  f\left(\sum_i r_i \alpha_i + v'\right) = c f(v)$$ Hence $g = c f$, QED.

Comment: A few initial comments: It is not true that $\mathrm{im} f \cong \mathrm{im} g$ as $g$ might be zero (if $c = 0$) but $f$ can be non-zero. Second, in proving $(1)$, you have replace the role of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @levap: thanks, fixed these things

Comment: Note that your proof shows that $c(kv) = c(v)$ only if $f(v) \neq 0$. That is, for $v \notin \ker(f)$. Also, it's not entirely clear from what you wrote why what you show is enough if $\operatorname{rank} f = 1$. Furthermore, you can't apply $g$ to $\alpha_x + \alpha_y$ as $\alpha_x + \alpha_y \in W$ while $g$ has $V$ as a domain.

Comment: Why should $f(a_i)$ and $f(a_j)$ be linearly independant? Note that a linear transformation sends a linealy independant set to a linearly independant iff it is injective!

Comment: @M.U. I switched the letters in the middle of writing, forgot to change them. Changed the denotation of the basis.

Comment: @levap I'll do fixes regarding the first two comments tomorrow. As for the third, see the previous comment.

Comment: Your map $c$ is only well-defined for $v \notin \ker f$.

Comment: @levap is everything correct after my fixes?

Comment: @marmistrz Two comments: I'm not sure what you mean by "define $c(v)$ for $v \notin \ker f$". It is given to you that a function $v \mapsto c(v)$ exists for all $v \in V$ so you don't need to define it. The more important issue is that in your final line, you write $f(v) = f \left( \sum_{i \in I} r_i \alpha_i \right)$ and this suggests that any $v \in V$ can be written as $\sum_{i \in I} r_i \alpha_i$ and this is not true. Any element in $v$ can be written (uniquely) as $\sum_{i \in I} r_i \alpha_i + v'$ where $v' \in \ker f$ and this is enough together with $\ker f \subseteq \ker g$.

Comment: Finally, you again replaced the role of $f$ and $g$ in the final line.

Comment: @levap thanks! fixed what you remarked

Comment: In the end, I would write: Let $v \in V$. Writing $f(v) = \sum_{i \in I} r_i f(\alpha_i)$, we can set $v' = v - \sum_{i \in I} r_i \alpha_i$ and then $v = \sum_{i \in I} r_i \alpha_i + v'$ and $f(v') = 0$ (and so $g(v') = 0$). Then ...

Comment: Or maybe a little shorter: for $v' = pr_{\ker f} v$, since $V = \ker f \oplus f^{-1}(\im f)$?